# Layouts are not updated when navigated back with different device orientation

Tags: ios, layout, uiviewcontroller, autorotate, device-orientation

I have a custom tab bar controller with 4 tabs which manages 4 view controllers, and I support rotation of the device. When I tap one of the tab items and the corresponding view controller and associated view are loaded and shown, changes in the layout by rotating the device are ok. However if, for example, I'm showing a view with the device in portrait orientation, then I tap another tab item and its corresponding view is shown, I rotate this view to landscape, and then, still being in landscape, I go again to the first view by taping its tab item, then such view, that was in portrait when it disappeared, is now in landscape with the portrait sizes and appearance (right-half of the screen is empty and views go out in height)...

What is the way to update the layouts in such situations?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have a similar problem only on iOS 7.